# Checking vowels on tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

```
root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x300")
root.title("Welcome to the vowel checker. - Logged in as: " + displayedtitle)

userWord = Entry(root, width= 50)
userWord.pack()

def vwlchck():
    letter = str
    for letter in userWord:
        if letter == 'A':
            continue
        elif letter == 'E':
            continue
        elif letter == 'I':
            continue
        elif letter == 'O':
                continue
        elif letter == 'U':
                continue
        else:
            vowllabel = Label(root, text=letter.get())
            vowllabel.pack()

thebutton = Button(root, text="Check Vowl", command=vwlchck)
thebutton.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Basically Im trying to create a tkinter GUI to ask the user for their username (needed for other portions of the project) and then asks them to write anything in the field, then using a for loop to check for letters that are vowels, it then displays the vowels as a label.
So in the code above, I keep getting the error code when I try and press the button "Check Vowl":

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Omar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "c:\Users\Omar\Desktop\python course\testing.py", line 25, in vwlchck
    for letter in userWord:
  File "C:\Users\Omar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1652, in cget
    return self.tk.call(self._w, 'cget', '-' + key)
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
```

I only get this error when trying to implement the check vowel in
tkinter GUI, when Im using normal print in console, it works fine...

Comment: To get the current value of `userWord`, use `for letter in userWord.get():`.

Comment: I tried to find a duplicate for this question, but everything I could find involved the asker already being able to do this part and having a more complex problem. What happened when you tried following a tkinter tutorial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To just fix the errors in your code, you need to, as [@martineau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/355230/martineau) pointed out, change `for letter in Userword:` to `for letter in Userword.get()`.

Then, another error arises from using `letter.get()` when creating the label, so just remove the `.get()`.

---

Without changing any other functionality, you could use something like this:

```
root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x300")
root.title("Welcome to the vowel checker. - Logged in as: " + displayedtitle)

userWord = Entry(root, width=50)
userWord.pack()


def vwlchck():
    for letter in userWord.get():
        if letter.upper() not in "AEIOU":
            vowllabel = Label(root, text=letter)
            vowllabel.pack()


thebutton = Button(root, text="Check Vowl", command=vwlchck)
thebutton.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

---

I'm not sure the `vwlchck` function does what you want it to, as it will create a new label for every non-vowel character it in the entry, so let me know if you want it to do something else (it's the same as would happen with how you currently have the function, I just changed all the `if` statements into one check).